# Is there underscorejs object constructor that takes " _('string') " format?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, netsuite

I am working on a html template and dissecting it (Suitecommerce Reference Impl to be more specific - an ERP solution which comes with webfront features).

Here's a snippet from the template.

```
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-touchpoint="customercenter" data-hashtag="#ordershistory">
                        <%= _('Order History').translate() %>
        </a>
    </li>
```

The % tag between normal html tags are written in backbonejs and underscorejs.

Since underscorejs functions take _.function() form, I don't get  the purpse of _('string').

Any backbonejs/underscorejs developers out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `_(obj)` Underscore wraps the `obj` argument. Then any Underscore methods can be called on the wrapped object without having to modify the prototype of `obj`.

It appears that one of the libraries that you are using has added the `translate()` method to the Underscore prototype and the `_(string).translate()` is the way to call that method on your string.

Here is another example of extending Underscore in a similar manner:

```js
_.mixin({
  logToConsole: function(str) {
    console.log(str)
  }
})

_('text to log').logToConsole()
```

References:

[Underscore OOP (wrapping)](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#oop)

[Underscore mixin method](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin)

Comment: Thank you. While I believe you, I was testing my documentation search skills (So to avoid asking too much questions?!) but couldn't find any underscore documents (http://underscorejs.org/) discussing uderscore wrapping objects. Do you know official doc that talks about this "wrapping"?

Comment: Yes. The first link that I've added to the edit covers it a bit (the annotations to the source code).

Comment: @learnNetsuite If you search the [official docs](http://underscorejs.org) for `_(` you'll see it mentioned in a few places, AFAIK the change log entry for 0.4.0 is the closest thing to an "official" mention.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a translation library, meant to translate the text into the language specified in the user's browser, possibly something like [this one](http://www.localeplanet.com/api/translate.html)?

On the documentation page for `translate.js`, it looks like you can call the function using traditional `underscore.js` style, or you can send the primary argument in the underscore function:

> `_.translate(text...)` - this is the main translate function and is also the base object (i.e. you can call `_(text)`). Translates the first parameter. If called with multiple parameters, it will call a "format" function with the 1st parameter translated followed by the additional parameters.

It's very common convention for translation libraries to be accessed using an underscore function (for an example, [see Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/)): `translated_text = _('Text to translate')`

I would suggest looking in the scripts to see if a language translation library is in use.